# Traverse the tree with Capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I want to do something that I think should be quite simple but can't work it out. 
Using Cucumber and Capybara

In a table I want to click a button in the same row, but a different cell.

i.e. I want to find the button 'Change Role' that is in the same row as the name "Bob Perkins"

click_button "Change Role" within

I want to do something like

```
within find("td", text:"Bob Perkins").parent #where this would be the "tr" row
click_link_or_button("Change Role")
```

But that's giving me an ambigous match on "Change Role". Sure, there are more on the page, but only one of them is in the parent node of where it should be...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parent node in Capybara?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861863/how-to-get-parent-node-in-capybara)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a bit of a play with capybara it looks as if the parent method returns the whole html document

```
e = find "table > thead"
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="thead">
e.parent
=> #<Capybara::Document>
```

The default selector type for capybara is CSS and that does not support the parent selector
It may be worth looking at XPath as with XPath you can perform a contains

```
e = find :xpath, "//table[thead]"
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="table">

e = find :xpath, "//table[thead]", text: "TOTAL"
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="table">
```

So looking at your code you could try this:

```
e = find :xpath, "//tr[td[contains(text(),'Bob Perkins')]]"
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="tr">
```

OR

```
e = find :xpath, "//tr[td]", text: 'Bob Perkins'
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="tr">
```

So you should get something like this

```
within find(:xpath, "//tr[td[contains(text(),'Bob Perkins')]]") do
  click_link_or_button("Change Role")
end
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how many people are fluent in xpath, but if you find it as confusing as I do, you can chain finds to utilize xpath only as necessary.  So for instance:

```
find("td", text:"Bob Perkins").find(:xpath, '..') # Gives you the TR
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost close the answer.

Corrected one is the:

```
within(find("td", text:"Bob Perkins").parent){ click_link_or_button("Change Role") }
```