# Capybara: click_button with no text or id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, capybara, scraper

Here is the html code:

```
<button type="button" class="icl-Button--transparent icl-Button--sm ia-AddCoverLetter-button"><span class="icl-ButtonIcon"><svg aria-label="Add cover letter" class="icl-Icon icl-Icon--blue icl-Icon--sm" role="img"><g><path d="M9.75,5.25H8.25v3h-3v1.5h3v3h1.5v-3h3V8.25h-3v-3ZM9,1.5A7.5,7.5,0,1,0,16.5,9,7.5,7.5,0,0,0,9,1.5ZM9,15a6,6,0,1,1,6-6A6,6,0,0,1,9,15Z"></path></g></svg></span>Add cover letter</button>
```

How would you get capybara to click on it when it has no name or id. I tried click_link('Add cover letter') but it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to select it by it's class, have you tried that?

```
find('button.ia-AddCoverLetter-button').click
```

Comment: How did you know what part of class= to pick. do you just pick the one that starts with "ia"?

Comment: No you can pick any class that there is.  I picked that one because I try to keep away from css classes as a general rule.  You want to pick a class that is less likely to change or get removed to use in a test, that one just seemed to be specific to that button (although only someone who really knows that app will know for sure).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer will work fine, however if you want to stay using `click_button` to make your code clearer to read (`click_button` not `click_link` since it's a button not a link) you could also do

```
click_button(class: 'ia-AddCoverLetter-button')
```

or if you want to specify more than one class you can pass an array

```
click_button(class: ['icl-Button--transparent', 'icl-Button--sm', 'ia-AddCoverLetter-button'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while looking for a way to click on an item based on it's `aria-label` (as the OP tried to do but couldn't get to work).

In general this can now (since [August 2016](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/1732)) be done by enabling an option for Capybara to match ARIA labels. In Rails system tests, this is achieved by adding `Capybara.enable_aria_label = true` to `application_system_test_case.rb`:

```
# test/application_system_test_case.rb
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
  Capybara.enable_aria_label = true
end
```

With that option turned on, to click on an icon link like this one (using HAML):

```
= link_to edit_reader_path(reader), 'aria-label' => 'Edit' do
  %i.icon-pencil.m-auto.text-primary{'aria-hidden' => 'true'}
```

...I can just write something like this in my system test:

```
click_on 'Edit', match: :first
```

I'm assuming this would need to be tweaked to suit the OP's situation where the `aria-label` is on an SVG nested within a span, within the button, perhaps by finding the SVG and then finding its parent's [parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861863/how-to-get-parent-node-in-capybara).